# Safety switch on NEC projector

Tags: switches, identification

I've got NEC projector with broken switch with turns the projector off when lamp cover isn't in-place.

I simply cannot identify this switch. There are thousands of switches on online shops who specialize in selling electronic components.

What is the name or part number of such switch?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Such a switch would generally be known as an "interlock switch".  To give you any help you'd need to provide a much clearer picture, ideally a direct top view.  Better yet , try to look up a service manual for the projector model you have.

Comment: Just bypass it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching on Digikey I have found the switch. It is called "switch detector", lies in category "limit switches"

Manufacturer Part no.: TD1105A

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/e-switch/TD1105A/EG2661-ND/807942

[image]